# Windows Install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, cd-drive

Ok I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 on all of my computers and want to put windows 7 back on my desk top, I boot from the cd everything looks to start normal, after clicking install windows 7 it comes up with a error saying "No device drivers were found. Make sure that the installation media contains the correct drivers, and then click OK." Even though I have no problems using the CD/DVD drive in ubuntu why is it coming up with this error during my windows 7 install?

Comment: Try doing it with another bootable windows cd/dvd/usb, Maybe the probem is with the bootable windows cd/dvd

Comment: Made another disc on ubuntu of a different iso file that one wouldn’t boot at all. Trying to make a bootable usb but I feel I will have no luck.

Comment: I dont feel its a duplicate they want to install without loosing there ubuntu files I myself am not worried I want to format the drive and install but I cant.

Comment: As aside note for my answer I'd ask for why do you wanna go back in Windows? If it is the visual look, i.e. Unity, then you could install another DE, for example KDE is pretty much great.

Comment: @mikewhatever no, it is not. The question is not how to install Windows, but why Ubuntu installation disc works fine, while the Windows one fails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as it says, that there's no device drivers found. The GNU/Linux *(e.g. Ubuntu)* installation disc works fine because by default there's a bunch of drivers. This is one of differences between how GNU/Linux distros and Windows are shipped.

For more obvious example, imagine you just installed Windows and Ubuntu. If you would look for you GPU device at *device manager* in Windows, you'll most probably find something like «Generic Vesa compatible GPU» *(not exactly this, I don't remember the wording, but the point is that you won't see something exact like «AMD Radeon HD5730» or «Mobility Radeon HD 5730 / 6570M»)*. Additionally, sometimes the resolution screwed. To fix things you need to go to manufacter's site, find, and download the drivers for GPU *(and first hope that at least your ethernet is working )*.

However, this is not the case with GNU/Linux distros. Usually, after you boot up to the system, everything Just Works™. Yeah, there still could be e.g. some problem with proprietary WiFi drivers, however they're more rare than they're in Windows, and in the given example you already have GPU driver shipped with the system, you can just upgrade it with a couple of clicks if you want to.

Now, if you'd want to additionally ask for how to fix the problem that Windows disc didn't have proper drivers — well, I think you'd better ask it in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). Besides the fact, that the question would be offtopic, I'm pretty sure, most peoples here are ways better in GNU/Linux than they're in Windows. It's just that is a proprietary OS, with a bunch of black magic behind the curtains, so it is hard to say what it does without closer research. You could either do that research yourself, or ask e.g. at SuperUser hoping someone already met the problem, did the research, and have a workaround.